# How to display the selected items in a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The issue is that selected item is not showing up in input field.

```js
export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("");
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState("");
  const [delivery, setDelivery] = useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, id } = event.target;

    if (id === "sortBySelect") {
      setSortBy(value);
    } else if (id === "conditionSelect") {
      setCondition(value);
    } else if (id === "deliverySelect") {
      setDelivery(value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: "136px" }}>
        <InputLabel id="sortBylabel">Sort By</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="sortBylabel"
          id="sortBySelect"
          value={sortBy}
          label="Sort By"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={1}>The cheapest</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={2}>The most expensive</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={3}>Top-rated</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: "136px" }}>
        <InputLabel id="conditionLabel">Condition</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="conditionLabel"
          id="conditionSelect"
          value={condition}
          label="Condition"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={4}></MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={5}></MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={6}></MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: "136px" }}>
        <InputLabel id="deliveryLabel">Delivery</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="deliveryLabel"
          id="deliverySelect"
          value={delivery}
          label="Delivery"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={7}></MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={8}></MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={9}></MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

I think I need to add another state to store the chosen item in `<InputLabel>`, but I got lost creating the condition - how I can store the "name" of the `<MenuItem>`, because the value is not equal to the name (what was in MUI demo code as well)

[image: Example of missing selected item]

Comment: Hi Maria, not sure if you already saw the answer below. But think about how you would be updating the `value` of each of the `<Select>` items in the `handleChange` handler you wrote. Can you write a function that knows which item's value has to be changed, and what vakue to change it to?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to map a value from a select input to an object.
To do this in a way that supports native selects, you'll need to ensure the value of the select remains a string and keep a separate record of what string values map to what objects.

One way to do this would be to keep a list of possible objects the select should map to.

i.e. take a list `items`, map over it to create the possible select options, and use `Array.find` to access the selected object.

```
export default function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const items = [
    {
      value: 'foo',
      label: 'Foo',
    },
    {
      value: 'bar',
      label: 'Bar',
    },
  ];
  const selectedItem = items.find(item => item.value === value);
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1 }} variant="standard">
        <InputLabel id="example-label-id">Value</InputLabel>
        <Select
          id="example-input-id"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Value"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>Not selected</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <MenuItem key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(selectedItem, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: screen cap of example]